# creating .xlsm file from a string data

Tags: java, xlsm

I need some help with creating .xlsm file from a string data in java. 
I have a .xlsm file with multiple sheets, stored as text in sybase database. I read this file content from the database in a java string and now I want to create .xlsm file from this string data. is this possible ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: You mean to say that whole content of your .xlsm file is stored in database. And it is stored in text or is it a blob object?

Comment: yes whole content of .xlsm is stored in sybase database as text data type

Comment: If the code for storing the file as text doesnt do any manipulation than you can simply read the text from database and create a file out of it with extension .xlsm. Have you tried that out ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohammed. Tried what you have suggested but when try to open the file which is created from the data stored in database, it says file is corrupted.

Comment: btw, found solution on the line you suggestion Mohammed. :) I stored the file file content as image data type and read it as byte stream and wrote to the file. thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to solve on your own. Storing the file content to BLOB object is the correct approach. You can add your solution as answer and mark your answer as accepted.